# Q: How to add multiple objects AR dectection

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I added an ar function into my app to dectect our products. One object is working but i want to add multiple arobject files. I scanned some objects and added them into my ar recource group.
I created a product.sks and added a label + background.
[image]
My first question: How can i fix the label to one object? I have two arobjects at the moment so i need 2 different labels. How can i differ the correct label to an object?

My second question: At the moment my HU label is fixed and doesnt move when i'm moving my iPhone. I tried to change some positions etc. but its always fixed.
How can i make it move?

Thanks in advance. I hope my concern is detailed enough

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ARViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    sceneView.delegate = self


    sceneView.showsStatistics = true


    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/scene.scn")!


    sceneView.scene = scene
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    configuration.detectionObjects = ARReferenceObject.referenceObjects(inGroupNamed: "Module", bundle: Bundle.main)!


    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)


    sceneView.session.pause()
}


 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
 let node = SCNNode()

 return node
 }


func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let node = SCNNode()

    if let objectAnchor = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(objectAnchor.referenceObject.extent.x * 0.8), height: CGFloat(objectAnchor.referenceObject.extent.y * 0.5))
        plane.cornerRadius = plane.width * 0.125

        let displayScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "product")

        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = displayScene
        plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1), 0, 1, 0)

        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(objectAnchor.referenceObject.center.x, objectAnchor.referenceObject.center.y + 0.12, objectAnchor.referenceObject.center.z)

        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    }
    return node
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // Present an error message to the user

}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay

}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required

}
```

}

Comment: What is the added value of SKScene as SCNPlane material comparing to SCNText? BTW you can also use SpriteKit directly in ARKit, and add SKLabelNode.

Comment: I used a sample code, this was my first try with ar. Do you think the spritekit is easier? Are you able to help me maybe?

Comment: The code is und working fine, i just want to add more objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `anchor.referenceObject.name`?
2. Move how? If you want it to always face the phone, apply billboard constraint.

Comment: 1. Where should i add the anchor name? 2. Correct, i‘ll try it!